# Installed roots/sage but has warnings after executing npm run start

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I already have installed sage but after running npm run install has warnings and I'm clueless about it.

I just ran npm run install but warnings appear.

Here is the warning messages:

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/uploads/cache/485a96430bd2c88cddd6eda5496bb717ca6cdee3.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/themes/sage/vendor/illuminate/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122

Warning: include(/home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/uploads/cache/485a96430bd2c88cddd6eda5496bb717ca6cdee3.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/themes/sage/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line 43

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/uploads/cache/485a96430bd2c88cddd6eda5496bb717ca6cdee3.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /home/leo/Desktop/wp/wp-content/themes/sage/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line 43

I expected the sage installation to smoothly run without warnings.

Comment: Just a question, Wordpress is installed On your Desktop??

Comment: yep. I added a virtual host for it